# documentFragment performance vs. appendChild on unattached element?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I'm creating a lot of DOM elements with Javascript, does adding them to a documentFragment then adding the fragment to the document, offer better performance than adding them to an ***unattached*** element then adding that element to the DOM? i.e.

```
var el;
var i = 0;
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

while (i < 2000) {
    el = document.createElement('li');
    el.innerText = 'This is my list item number ' + i;
    fragment.appendChild(el);
    i++; }

document.appendChild(fragment);
```

vs.

```
var el;
var i = 0;
var container = document.createElement('div');

while (i < 2000) {
    el = document.createElement('li');
    el.innerText = 'This is my list item number ' + i;
    container.appendChild(el);
    i++; }

document.appendChild(container);
```

(Note: This is just a simplified example, in my actual code I'm adding many table rows and table elements.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I just measured exactly that:

```
function f1(){
    console.time("f1")
    let e = document.createElement("div")
    for(let i=0; i < 100000; i++){
        let a = document.createElement("a")
        e.appendChild(a)
    }
    console.timeEnd("f1")
}

function f2(){
    console.time("f2")
    let e = document.createDocumentFragment()
    for(let i=0; i < 100000; i++){
        let a = document.createElement("a")
        e.appendChild(a)
    }
    console.timeEnd("f2")
}
```

documentfragment is relevantly faster:

```
f1: 494.0458984375ms      
f2: 346.35009765625ms
```

This is chrome, firefox is similar.

I thought it would be the same. Next question is where the overhead comes from.

Comment: 2021: measured again. chrome: f1 = 140ms f2 = 130ms. firefox: f1 = 90ms f2 = 90ms. yeah firefoxies, great job! looks like for creating unattached dom subtrees it does not make a serious difference anyore.

Comment: f2 code does not appending documentfragment into an element, in the end we will have to append document fragment to an element. If we will do that - f2 will be slower, i guess because there will be another  process to extract childs from document fragment to element.

Comment: good point, the test should include that step, agreed.

Answer (score 0):

From first principles i would speculate that using an actual wrapper Element should either be as fast or even marginally faster than a DocumentFragment. The speedup would result from less work needed to notify mutation observers and a single node having to be appended to the child list instead of unpacking the fragment and moving all its children over to the list. It would actually depend on the underlying datastructure. an array would have a higher penality than a rope structure.

If you want to be certain you have to write a benchmark and test it on all major browsers and occasionally re-test as new versions are released since their implementations change.

Well, you actually didn't even state that you're using a browser. There are also other DOM implementations.

Answer (score 0):

This JSPerf has `DocumentFragment` significantly beating `appendChild`, although `innerHTML` significantly beats both:

https://jsperf.com/appendchild-vs-documentfragment-vs-innerhtml/24

Answer (score 0):

Both the approaches mentioned in the question should have similar performance as we are inserting only one element/fragment in both case. But both cases will produce different DOM structure as with a `container` we are creating an actual element wrapper as compared to `fragment` where there will be no wrapper visible in DOM. Both approaches should trigger a single `reflow` here as we are inserting only one element/fragment.

Now lets compare the performance when we want to create same DOM structure. Here I would prefer using a `fragment` instead of appending `<li>` directly to the target node to avoid multiple `reflows`.

Let's create a long list as show below by using both approaches:

```html
<div id="target">
  <li>This is my list item number 0</li>
  <li>This is my list item number 1</li>
  <li>This is my list item number 2</li>
  <!-- Thousands of more list items -->
</div>
```

Here is a sample script I wrote to test the same using `performance` API. For me appending all `<li>` using a single `fragment` was little faster than directly appending each `<li>` to target node.

```js
function measureElement(target, testElementCount, index) {
  performance.mark(`element_start_${index}`); // Start
  for (let i = 0; i < testElementCount; i++) {
    let el = document.createElement('li');
    el.innerText = 'This is my list item number ' + i;
    target.appendChild(el);
  }
  performance.mark(`element_end_${index}`); // End
  performance.measure("element_measure", `element_start_${index}`, `element_end_${index}`);
}

function measureFragment(target, testElementCount, index) {
  performance.mark(`fragment_start_${index}`); // Start
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (let i = 0; i < testElementCount; i++) {
    let el = document.createElement('li');
    el.innerText = 'This is my list item number ' + i;
    fragment.appendChild(el);
  }
  target.appendChild(fragment);
  performance.mark(`fragment_end_${index}`); // End
  performance.measure("fragment_measure", `fragment_start_${index}`, `fragment_end_${index}`);
}

// Test Runner
function init() {
  const testCount = 10;
  const testElementCount = 100000;
  const target = document.querySelector("#target");
  let entries, total;

  console.log('------------------------- Measure Using Element -------------------------');
  for (let i = 0; i < testCount; i++) {
    target.innerHTML = "";
    measureElement(target, testElementCount, i);
  }
  entries = performance.getEntriesByName("element_measure");
  total = 0;
  for (const entry of entries) {
    total += entry.duration;
  }
  console.log(`Total Time for ${testCount} iteration with ${testElementCount} list items : ${total}`);
  console.log(`Average Time for ${testCount} iteration with ${testElementCount} list items : ${total/testCount}`);

  console.log('------------------------- Measure Using Fragment -------------------------');
  for (let i = 0; i < testCount; i++) {
    target.innerHTML = "";
    measureFragment(target, testElementCount, i);
  }
  entries = performance.getEntriesByName("fragment_measure");
  total = 0;
  for (const entry of entries) {
    total += entry.duration;
  }
  console.log(`Total Time for ${testCount} iteration with ${testElementCount} list items : ${total}`);
  console.log(`Average Time for ${testCount} iteration with ${testElementCount} list items : ${total/testCount}`);
}

init();
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

```
"------------------------- Measure Using Element -------------------------"
"Total Time for 10 iteration with 100000 list items : 2624.8000000044703"
"Average Time for 10 iteration with 100000 list items : 262.48000000044703"
"------------------------- Measure Using Fragment -------------------------"
"Total Time for 10 iteration with 100000 list items : 2526.7999999970198"
"Average Time for 10 iteration with 100000 list items : 252.67999999970198"
```