# Append array of element in single DOM reflow

Tags: javascript, html, append, appendchild

In JavaScript, the `element.append()` function accepts multiple parameters.

```
append(param1, param2, /* … ,*/ paramN)
```

I would like to append a set of elements in one time (for performance reason) to prevent reflow between call of `el.append()`.

Here is a simple example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let parent = document.getElementById('parent');

let array=[];    
for (let i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    array[i] = document.createElement("span");
    array[i].textContent = i;

    // Works OK
    //parent.append(array[i]);
}
    
// Does not work
document.getElementById('parent').append(array)
```

Here is the assocated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/amd0txg6/

Is there a way to append a set of element created dynamically (for example an array) at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to spread the array:

```
document.getElementById('parent').append(...array)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymputLn7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).

> Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation of element's position and geometry). Historically, using document fragments could result in better performance.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');

const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = i;
  frag.append(span);
}
    
parent.append(frag);
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can make use of a `fragment` to avoid reflow on multiple insertions. For instance,

```js
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = i;
  fragment.appendChild(span);
}

document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(fragment);
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Any idea which one is fastest between Alan's solution and yours?

Comment: @Fifi document fragment is much faster. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53555918/2425366

Answer (score -1):

if you want to append a set of element created dynamically (for example an array) at once you can use `append()` from jQuery